# Problems with react-admin components

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I'm trying to use a **TabbedShowLayout** inside of **Edit** but this return a error related the missing props:

[print of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZemG.png)

Here is my code:

```js
export const BarberEdit = (props) => {
  const [id, setId] = useState(props.id);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
  const [birthday, setBirthday] = useState(Date);
  const [transport, setTransport] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  function handleSubmit() {
    console.log("alguma coisa.");
  }

  return (
    <Edit {...props} title={<BarberEditTitle />}>
      <TabbedShowLayout>
        <Tab label="Perfil">
          <SimpleForm submitOnEnter={false}>
            <TextInput source="name" />
            <TextInput source="phone" />
            <DateInput source="birthday" />
            <TextInput source="transport" />
            <TextInput source="email" />
          </SimpleForm>
        </Tab>

        <Tab label="Endereço">
          <ReferenceManyField
            label=""
            reference="barbers_addresses"
            target="barberId"
          >
            <Datagrid>
              <TextField source="street" label="Rua" />
              <TextField source="city" label="Cidade" />
              <TextField source="district" label="Bairro" />
            </Datagrid>
          </ReferenceManyField>
        </Tab>
      </TabbedShowLayout>
    </Edit>
  );
};
```

Reading the [react-admin](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#the-simpleform-component) documentation a bit, i found that **SimpleForm** has two inherited properties.

thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you remove all the children of `TabbedShowLayout` and add them back again one at a time (eg. add one, delete it, add another, delete it, repeat)?

Comment: Please post text, not links to images of text.

Comment: @McKayM I believe that we will arrive at the same result, because the error is when inheriting properties or not. Then at some point he would appear again

Comment: @DaveNewton 
my account is recent and because of that I still don't have permission to post images, just link to reference them :(

Comment: ... You're allowed to post text. It's a picture of text. Post the text, not a picture of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Edit and Create layout, you should use TabbedForm, and not TabbedShowLayout,
also, there is no need to use SimpleForm as Tab child, and you can pass submitOnEnter directly to TabbedForm

```
export const BarberEdit = (props) => {
  const [id, setId] = useState(props.id);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
  const [birthday, setBirthday] = useState(Date);
  const [transport, setTransport] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  function handleSubmit() {
    console.log("alguma coisa.");
  }

  return (
    <Edit {...props} title={<BarberEditTitle />}>
      <TabbedForm submitOnEnter={false}>
        <FormTab label="Perfil">
            <TextInput source="name" />
            <TextInput source="phone" />
            <DateInput source="birthday" />
            <TextInput source="transport" />
            <TextInput source="email" />
        </FormTab>

        <FormTab label="Endereço">
          <ReferenceManyField
            label=""
            reference="barbers_addresses"
            target="barberId"
          >
            <Datagrid>
              <TextField source="street" label="Rua" />
              <TextField source="city" label="Cidade" />
              <TextField source="district" label="Bairro" />
            </Datagrid>
          </ReferenceManyField>
        </FormTab>
      </TabbedForm>
    </Edit>
  );
};
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks you for your contribution! I just made some adjustments, because TabbedForm does not work together with Tab, but FormTab. Everything worked again :)

Comment: You are right. I edited the answer wih FormTab. Nice that everything is working.